# Split string in java when content is not known

Tags: java

I have a string that contains some data. I want to split it based on a pattern but a part of the pattern cannot be known. I have my code here:

```
String consolidated = getFileContents(fileName);
String newlines[] = null;
if(consolidated!="")
{
newlines=consolidated.split("---------------------SAVED BY ####### ----------------");
}
```

In the code, the "#######" is dynamic and consists of user name and differs from file to file. I cannot keep it static. How can i split it?

Comment: You'll probably want to use regular expressions: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

Comment: What form can the unknown bit take?

Comment: Another option is to split it on the first hyphens and second hyphens, if they are different lengths. And then just ignore the second and first elements (respectively)

Comment: Something like `tempLines1=consolidated.split("---------------------")` ,`tempLines2=consolidated.split("----------------")`. Then go through both arrays and if you find an element that contains ("SAVED BY"), ignore it. (It means that you want to ignore the item). I can write a solution if you'd like; I just don't have a Java IDE right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
String username = "";
//read username from file
//split by username
newlines=consolidated.split("---------------------SAVED BY "+ username +" ----------------");
```

Comment: the username is already pre written to a file and is not current username